# Error when deleting a UITableViewRow, index of row clicked not in range of possible indexes

Tags: swift, uitableview, option-type

I have a problem when deleting an item manually using a custom button, when the amount of items (variable of the cell), happening when the user clicks the minus sign at a value of that variable == 1. The cells correctly slide up as the previous one gets deleted, but then when all the cells below go up, the indexes do not change, even though I correctly remove both the cell and the value from my dictionary.

I tried to unable user activity on the screen, but still, that was not the issue as I understand it is a type index out of range error.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ordersTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "OrdersTableViewCell", bundle: .main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ordersTableViewCell")

    let cell = ordersTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ordersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OrdersTableViewCell
    let amount = dishesDictionary[indexPath.item]![4] as! Int 
    cell.dishAmountLabel.text = ("\(String(amount))x")



@objc func decreaseAmount(sender: UIButton){



    let index = sender.tag
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)

    if (dishesDictionary[index]![4] as! Int) > 1 {

        let numberOfItems = dishesDictionary[index]![4] as! Int
        dishesDictionary[index]![4] = numberOfItems - 1


        ordersTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        print(dishesDictionary[index])
        print("COUNT: \(dishesDictionary.count)")
    }

    else if (dishesDictionary[index]![4] as! Int) == 1 {

        ordersTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.dishesDictionary.removeValue(forKey: index)
        self.ordersTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        ordersTableView.endUpdates()
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7, execute: {
            self.ordersTableView.reloadData()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        })

    }

    else {
        return
    }
    calculateTotalAmount()
}
```

Comment: "let amount = dishesDictionary[indexPath.item]![4] as! Int". Shouldn't that be indexPath.section or indexPath.row?

Comment: Unrelated but never register cells a zillion times in `cellForRowAt`, register them once in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @vadian I’m yet to fix that, it’s the only part of the code where i’Ve still got to do it. And onnoweb, I forgot to mention that I do not use protocols, instead I use the .tag property to get the button tag, and add an action to it. Everything unimportant I deleted and figured out. I just can’t figure out a way to fix the indexes of the dictionary and table view (that gets the items from the dictionary) dynamically.

Comment: When you call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` you don't have to update your datasource. Try avoid using `begin` and `end` update

Comment: @Andrew21111 should that solve the issue? Or is it just good practice not to do it?